# Animating a single data file using gnuplot

Tags: animation, gnuplot

I use FORTRAN 77 code to generate data (saved as filename.dat) of simple physics situations containing x-y co-ordinates like a projectile.

My data files usually have 2 or 3 columns like so:

```
1 1
2 2
3 3
4 4
5 5
```

I can plot (2d and 3d) using Gnuplot just fine but I want to animate the point and make it look like a real projectile on the graph and then save it as a .gif file.

I am new to bash scripts so please assume I do not know a single thing about scripts, if it involves using those.

Thanks!

Comment: You can follow the instructions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28671129/gnuplot-and-sierpinksi-triangle/28687379#28687379

Comment: In the link you posted, under the section "To monitor how the triangle gets created dot by dot you can use a loop with a pause:" Where do I type this?

Comment: Except for the `convert ...` line it's all gnuplot code. The `pause` within the loop allows you to see how things change without leaving gnuplot (that is on the popup terminal).

Comment: Problem solved. I had seen the answer that you posted before you did but it hadn't worked. The code in that required gnuplot version 4.6 or above and I did not have that. Once I updated it, started working like a charm. On a side note, why are people downvoting my question? Is it because its a silly one?

Comment: I did not downvote it, but I suspect it's because of the tags, which are wrong. In particular the Fotran tag. It's not really a bash question, or a physics one. Once the first downvote happens other people might be more prone to further downvote. An experienced user would usually post the reason for downvote in the comments but who knows who downvoted here.

Comment: Thanks for you help! Changed the tags. Also I noticed that the answers here, in general, require certain level of knowledge which many beginners like myself wouldn't have...Maybe answers should be more detailed and open to people just getting into things.

Comment: Answers are provided by volunteers out of their free time. I for one am usually quite busy. So a certain amount of work is expected from the poster. Bear that in mind. Once you get used to the system you'll find this site very useful.

Comment: Agreed. That is why when you linked me and it was not working, I didn't just come here and say that its not working. All I'm saying is that it can be a little intimidating at first being used to sites like quora where answers are truly of a quality that even a kid could follow most of it. Yeah, I know this is different, a little more professional and a little more technical than quora. I'll get used to it.

Comment: I downvoted your question, because it only said "I want to do this!", without giving the impression that you tried anything on your own. Yes, many answer require some previous knowledge, but there are also many answers explaining the very basics. You must only take some time to learn gnuplot's basics. And many answers are also quite detailled, but you cannot expect every answer to explain all details. Imagine you would need to write five pages each time to explain all basics before you come to the actual answer. Impossible and not the purpose of this site.

Comment: Please move your solution into an answer and accept it. That is perfectly valid, and we can close this issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem solved. This is the code I am using:

```
set terminal gif animate delay 100
set output 'output.gif'
stats 'data.dat' nooutput
set xrange [-0.5:1.5]
set yrange [-0.5:5.5]

do for [i=1:int(STATS_blocks)] {
   plot 'data.dat' index (i-1) with circles
}
```

Gnuplot version 4.6 or higher is required for this to work. This code must be entered in gnuplot. This requires the data to be in the following format:

```
1 1


2 2


3 3


4 4
```