# Gnuplot: Making gif animation file with 1500 data files

Tags: animation, gnuplot, gif

I have a sequence of **1500 data files** named like: 1.dat, 2.dat.....1500.dat, and I want to use gif terminal in gnuplot to make a gif file. I wrote a script to do this, **which works pretty good if the number of the data file is not too large. When I tried to make a gif file using 1500 datafiles, the output is a broken file that can not be opened**

I post my code as follow, the out.plt file is used to set up gif terminal and then load "loop.plt"; "loop.plt" is used to looping over all the data files:

```
#start of out.plt file
#This is used to load the loop file
#set up basis config

i=1
n=1500
set title "Suppressing Spiral Wave with Planar Wave"
set size ratio 1
set terminal gif animate delay 15 loop 1500
set output "control_spiral1.gif"
load "loop.plt"
set output

#end of out.plt file
```

and here is the loop.plt file:

```
#start of loop.plt
#This is the loop file to plot all data files


set pm3d map

set palette gray
splot sprintf("%d.dat",i) matrix

i=i+1

if(i<=n) reread

#end of loop.plt
```

Comment: You could use an external tool, for example `convert`. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28671129/gnuplot-and-sierpinksi-triangle/28687379#28687379

Comment: Thanks for your answer Miguel! I have plotted all my data files to .png images, and I tried to use convert as you've suggested. The command I used is "convert -delay 10 -loop 0 *.png animation.gif", however, this also gives a .gif file that cannot be opened.

Comment: You can also convert images to movie, see for example: http://robotics.usc.edu/~ampereir/wordpress/?p=702

Comment: You have copied the file out.plt twice instead of showing us both files, out.plt and loop.plt. Can you update your question?

Comment: @maij Thanks for the heads up maij! I have updated the "loop.plt" file in the answer below.

Comment: @Cory.Z Perhaps the Gif file is too large. Have you tried different viewer? As somebody wrote, you can try with a video.

Comment: @Miguel I think you are correct. I have tried to use ffmpeg and it works pretty well. Thanks again!

Comment: Note that using the `do for [i=1:n] { ... }` structure would allow you a much improved code,  within a single file.